# How to store array input into database? MYSQL PHP form input foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, arrays

In this project, I am making an attendance user interface for the teacher. Here teacher can update student's marks which will directly update into the MYSQL database. Below shows the code that I used to echo out the list of students from the database. Here, I have used array i.e. name="gradeEdit[]" in input section.

teacherGrades.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("#", "#", "", "#");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$result = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT ");
echo ' <form method="POST" action="teacherGrades.php"> 
  <table class="tableEchoPupil" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
<td> <input type='text' name='gradeEdit[]' /> </td> 
</tr>"; }

echo "<input class='gradeSubmit' type='submit' name='btnSubmit' value='Submit'>"; 
echo "</table>"; 
echo "</form> <br/>"; 
 ?>
```

Below shows the code that is stored in the beginning of this page [teacherGrades.php
]. When the teacher inputs new grades and click the submit button from the previous code, the grades has to updated in the database. However the problem is that, I am not able to update it properly. I think there is a few problem behind my code, can you please check and help me. If there are further questions, I am ready to answer.

Thank you in advance.

```
 <?php 
 $con=mysqli_connect("#","#","","#");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 if ($_POST['btnSubmit']){

 $gradeEdit = $_POST['gradeEdit']; 

    foreach ($gradeEdit as $key => $value) {

      $grades = implode(',', $gradeEdit);

      $query = "UPDATE classroom_student_teacher SET marks = '$grades'
 WHERE teacher_id = $userid AND classroom_id = $id";

  $close = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
  }
  }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass student name or id in your input box. Which means row-1_key => row-1_value.

```
<input type='text' name='gradeEdit[".$row['student_id']."]' />
```

the above line is for form input. **Let me know Are you updating data for teacher or for all students. State me table structure.**

If you want to save array value. use the below line

```
foreach ($gradeEdit as $key => $value) {

//use $key as row id and marks will be your $value. So change your query like this below.

$row_id=$key+1;
$query = "UPDATE classroom_student_teacher SET marks = '$value'
WHERE student_id=$row_id AND teacher_id = $userid AND classroom_id = $id";
```

**AND teacher_id = $userid AND classroom_id = $id** why you using this condition

```
$close = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
}
```

Comment: When a teacher inputs marks for individual students and clicks the submit then the marks will get saved into the database.

Comment: In single row or multiple row?

Comment: Well it depends on the number of students in a class therefore multiple row is preferred. And the code you gave me where implode function is used gave me a message saying invalid arguments used in implode function.

Comment: I dont know why you are using teacher id as condition. so please state the table structure.

Comment: Which table structure you meant? Can you please let me know. In the question above there is the structure of the table that I have used to echo out the list of students in classroom taught by a specific teacher.

Comment: Since you are updating students marks where condition should be student name or id and you can add class id and teacher id should be additional values to table i.e., additional column

Comment: From the new code you updated, it gives me few answer but not accurate. So what it does now is for example, if I set A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 and D = 4 then it updates as A = 2, B = 3, C = 4 and d = N/A.

Comment: since array index starts with 0 use +1 to key in condition. If you can update it or wait a minute..

Comment: I will wait for you. I might make a mistake on the code.

Comment: The classroom_student_teacher table has student_id, classroom_id and teacher_id who are all foreign keys. I have set the condition WHERE classroom_id and teacher id such as such to recognise the teacher who edited the marks of a specific classroom.

Comment: check the above code.. The better way is to use student id as input key

Answer (score 0):

2 methods,

the json_encode is a possibility, but it might decode differently.

one option which sounds better to me would be to use serialize and unserialize, this will return the objects just as you put them.

e.g.

```
serialize($var);
unserialize($var);
```

It wil just make a serialized string of your array or objects.
In your case JSON could be fine too.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: I have never used json or other commands you have recommended. Well I will research about it and try to relate to my case study. thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: It's not always a good idea to use serialize or json, but when you need to store stuff which you're not sure what it holds it could prove usefull. have fun.

Answer (score 0):

To store data in you database you can use php own functions.

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("example.com","testuser","passwort","your_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO Your_Table (First, Second, Array)";
$sql .= VALUES ('First', 'Second',Your_Array)";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
```

To put your array in the database you can user the php function implode.

```
$array = array('First', 'Second', 'Last');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Wich will return you a string like this - First, Second, Last

Comment: I am trying to use UPDATE command to update the grades. Alongside I have already used implode command which you can see the question as well. When I use the implode command, it will echo out all the recorded values for all the students. For example, for A = 1 and B = 2, in result it shows A = 1, 2 and B = 1, 2

Comment: There is no matter in what you execute as long as your SQL is correct. I think if you implode your array this way, you will get some trouble exploding it again. As long as you treat the imploded array as a string there should be no problem in saving it to the database.